# PHP same form - two functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have this form here:

```
  <form  method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id={{$theme->id}}">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$theme->price}}">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$theme->id}}">
  <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> buy theme</button>
  </form>
```

When I execute this form (I press 'buy theme') the file starts downloading, but the problem is that the page itself doesn't refresh and I don't know how to make that. I want this form to work like that: I press the button - theme downloads + page refreshes or redirects just to homepage. Is it possible somehow ? Thanks.

BTW I'm using Laravel 5

**EDIT**

```
                header("Content-type: application/force-download");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".str_replace(" ", "_", $arr['file'])."\"");
                header('Location: index.php');
```

I added header('Location: index.php'); it redirects to the homepage, but download don't start then.

Route:

```
Route::get('/download', function(){
    return view('fileentries/download');
});
```

Comment: write your route instead of `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id={{$theme->id}}` in action.

Comment: But then I cannot download theme... with different route

Comment: can you share you `route.php` and `controller` file?

Comment: The download file is not made by controller. It's just seperate php file.

Comment: Use the framework instead of this mess ` <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id={{$theme->id}}`. Check the documents for the URL class. If you want to initiate a client event after download completes you will need javascript the server won't know when the client has finished downloading so not possible with laravel alone

Comment: you should escape `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`  with functions like `htmlspecialchars`  (Yes, it can be used to attack your site with XSS).

Comment: @undone Thanks, didn't know that. I just escaped that.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, possibly javascript is a solution here. Thanks

Comment: The only way to do this server side is to sleep your process for some arbitrary amount of time and then header the page. This is a terrible solution though only suggested to illustrate the issue

Comment: @MikeMiller Can u suggest the better solution then ? I've made it for now with Javascript

Comment: I already did - javascript is the only viable approach

Answer (score 0):

Write `header(location: homepage.php);` immediately after you execute the file download in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url()` helper function. It will generate a fully qualified URL to the given path. This function has three parameters: `url($path,$parameters,$secure)`. Provide the route path in the first parameter and the theme id in the second parameter.

Your form opening tag should look like this:

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ URL('/download',$theme->id) }}">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.